# Add Objects to Array Based on Condition JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a for Loop which send me 3 objects that I need to push into a new array of objects
The loop goes 3 times with this object each time

```
Time 1
0:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 301, Status: 0, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021}
1:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021}
2:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021}
```

```
Time 2
0:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 301, Status: 1, Day: 2, Month:1, Year:2021}
1:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 2, Month:1, Year:2021}
2:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 2, Month:1, Year:2021}
```

```
Time 3
0:{ Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 301, Status: 1, Day: 3, Month:1, Year:2021}
1:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 3, Month:1, Year:2021}
2:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 3, Month:1, Year:2021}
```

I need to store the data from this 3 arrays into a new object array only if Status==1 and if Number does not repeat
expecting the new array to contain exactly this

```
0:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021}
1:{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021}
```

Day, Month and Year are depreciable since I only need the new array to contain each "Number" that has Status=1 without adding the same Number again

I can't find myself to think how can I archive this

this is my approach so far but I have only be able to avoid adding the one line which contains Status=0

```
for(i=0;i<disponibilidad.length;i++)
        {
          if(disponibilidad[i].Estatus!=0)
          {
            if(this.disponibilidad.find(k=>k.Habitacion!=disponibilidad[i].Habitacion))
            {
            this.disponibilidad.push(disponibilidad[i])
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` and a Set to keep track of Numbers.

*Note I come up with 3 results from that collection Numbers 301, 302 & 303*

```js
const data = [{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 301, Status: 0, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021},
{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021},
{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021},
{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 301, Status: 1, Day: 2, Month:1, Year:2021},
{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 2, Month:1, Year:2021},
{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 2, Month:1, Year:2021},
{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 301, Status: 1, Day: 3, Month:1, Year:2021},
{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 3, Month:1, Year:2021},
{Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 3, Month:1, Year:2021}];

const nums = new Set()

const res = data.filter(({Number, Status}) => {
   return (!Status || nums.has(Number))? false : !!nums.add(Number);
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously not the shortest way of doing it, but it explains some basic logic. Well, one of multiple ways you can solve this.

```js
// Array
const arr = [
  [
    {Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 301, Status: 0, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021},
    {Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021},
    {Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 1, Month:1, Year:2021}
  ],[
    {Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 301, Status: 1, Day: 2, Month:1, Year:2021},
    {Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 2, Month:1, Year:2021},
    {Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 2, Month:1, Year:2021}
  ],[
    {Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 301, Status: 1, Day: 3, Month:1, Year:2021},
    {Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 303, Status: 1, Day: 3, Month:1, Year:2021},
    {Room: 'Shiraz', Number: 302, Status: 1, Day: 3, Month:1, Year:2021},
  ]
];

// Define resulting array
const res = [];
// Define blacklist array
const bl = [];
// Define used numbers array
const used = [];

// Loop array of arrays
for(a of arr) {
  // For each array loop it's items
  // First define blacklist
  for(i of a) {
    // If number already in blacklist array, skip cycle
    if(bl.indexOf(i.Number) !== -1) continue;
    // If status not 1, add number to blacklist
    if(i.Status !== 1) bl.push(i.Number);
  }
}

// Again loop array of arrays
for(a of arr) {
  // Then add items to resulting array
  for(i of a) {
    // If number in blacklist array, skip cycle
    if(bl.indexOf(i.Number) !== -1) continue;
    // If number in used array, skip cycle
    if(used.indexOf(i.Number) !== -1) continue;
    // Else push item
    res.push(i);
    // And add number to used array
    used.push(i.Number);
  }  
}

// Test
console.log(res);
```